# Why does std::align take in a reference to a pointer as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

This is the signature of [`std::align`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align)

```cpp
void* align( std::size_t alignment,
             std::size_t size,
             void*& ptr,
             std::size_t& space );
```

Why does it take in `void*&` if it already returns adjusted pointer? Am I missing something?

Comment: "The function modifies the pointer", example from link "if (std::align(a, sizeof(T), p, sz))"

Comment: This was introduced in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1546.pdf , and there is no rationale for modification of the argument. I do not see a compelling reason, and it seems like unnecessary limit in functionality (for example, we can't give pointers which are rvalues, i.e. results of certain operations).

Comment: Ok so I misinterpreted it. It uses return value only to indicate if the function failed and modifies passed reference.

Comment: It seems like the proposal was written with one very specific use case in mind, in which you intend to modify an existing pointers. It seems like an oversight to me, but it is too late to do anything about it now, we're stuck with it forever.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Time to break ABI to save C++

Comment: @MarcinPoloczek No you got it right, it returns `ptr` on success. `ptr` being modified is redundant information.

Comment: So it both returns and modifies it?

Comment: @MarcinPoloczek See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) : Return value The adjusted value of `ptr`, or null pointer value if the space provided is too small.